# Learn about regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

In an answer to one of my questions, someone had posted:

```
// could replace it with an easier to work with delimiter
str.replace(/(;)(?![";"])/g, '|')

// or split it, but skip over results that are just a ;
var strArr = str.split(/(;)(?![";"])/);
for (s in strArr) {
    if (strArr[s] !== ";") {
        // do something with strArr[s]
        console.log(strArr[s]);
    }
}
```

I'm completely lost at `/(;)(?![";"])/`. It looks like a bunch of random symbols to me :( .

Where can I learn more about regular expression syntax?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various resources:

- [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp)
- [The specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (but that's going to be hard going)
- JavaScript Kit's [intro](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml) and [reference](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml)
- evolt's [Regular Expressions in JavaScript](http://www.evolt.org/node/36435)

Regarding the actual expression, the `/` characters mark the beginning and end of the regular expression literal (like quotes do for a string, although the ending `/` may be followed by flags), and then:

```
     +------------- 1
     |+------------ 2
     ||+----------- 3
     ||| +--------- 4
     ||| |
     ||| |
     ||| | +------- 5
     ||| | | +----- 6
     ||| | | | +--- 7
     ||| | | | |+-- 8
     |||/ \|/ \||
    /(;)(?![";"])/
```

1. `(` starts a capture group in this case (because the `(` isn't followed by `?`, `=`, or `!` which change what it does)
2. `;` is a literal, it matches a semicolon
3. `)` ends the capture group
4. `(?!` Starts a "negative lookahead" so the overall expression only matches if what's inside the parentheses isn't found after the semicolon
5. `[` begins a character class, which matches any the characters within it
6. `";"` are the characters within the character class. (The second `"` is redundant.) The character class contains contains `;` and `"`.
7. `]` ends the character class
8. `)` ends the negative lookahead started in #4

So in all, match (and capture) a semicolon provided it's not followed immediately by a quote or semicolon. I can't see any particular reason for capturing the semicolon, but perhaps there was a reason in the context of the question where this was recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I have a [cheat sheet from visibone](http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/) that I refer back to frequently. I've found that really useful

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

The really confusing bit in that regular expression is the negative lookahead part which in javascript is represented using the `(?! ... )` syntax.  Once you understand that, the rest of it is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn anything is by doing. Here is a simple tester that will let you see what expressions do: https://regex101.com/